# Rooted phone, but can't pass "Install" dialog

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, security

I am running Android 4.4.4 with the LiquidSmooth ROM and SuperSU. All these components work flawlessly, as far as I can tell. I am also able to use TitanicBackup (to demonstrate Root is working).

However, whenever I try to install an app that queries for special permissions (like Xposed from XPrivacy), the installer presents me with a "Cancel" and "Install" button at the lower end of the screen, but I can only tap "Cancel", but not "Install" (which seems to be disabled).

Any idea what's going on and how to fix this? I can workaround by manually defining permissions in SuperSU, but if I need to install a temporary download from the browser, for instance, the app/apk name doesn't show up in SuperSU, so i can't enable it to allow installation... :-/

Comment: Have you tried a third party installer? Do you have any screen overlay apps running? Also no biggie but its titanium backup, not titanic…lol. Also did you disable all app restrict settings in any of the permission restricting apps and disable all Xposed modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, when you have installed some kind of overlay app like Twilight. It is a security feature against screen manipulation.
Solution: Find that app and disable it. After that you will be able to hit the Install button.

Comment: Thats assuming they have that problem, very speculative.

Comment: whew, I wasn't aware of that - had Bluelight Filter installed. Thanks!